# NGUI's UILabel is still visible on canvas even when it isn't enabled, how to fix it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have used NGUI's UILabel as HUD Text to show character's damage message in my game. The question is ,when the message's life end, I want to disappear the UILabel, I have tried but it is still visible on the screen. like this,
[image]

The UILabel's gameobject isn't active, UILabel's component isn't enabled and even label's alpha color is 0. But the UILabel still can be seen, How can I make it disappear.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens if you delete the object during play? If it doesn't disappear then you are not editing the correct thing.

Comment: It is still on screen when I delete gameobject,and I'm SURE I'm editing the corrent thing.